# Parameterize Start/Stop Date of Simulation Experiment via Method

Tags: anylogic

Is there a possibility to set the start and stop date of an simulation run using a function or parameter?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. These functions can be accessed via the *Engine* object. You can find the documentation of the class [here](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FEngine.html&cp=3_5_0_58). The functions you are looking for are:

- setStartDate(java.util.Date date)
- setStartTime(double tstart)
- setStopDate(java.util.Date date)
- setStopTime(double tstop)

Either in the Experiment or in the Main of your model, you can use (as an example) this code:

`getEngine().setStartTime(100);`

Of course, once the model is already started, only setting of stop time/date will have an effect.